# In Swift, advance on touch in splash screen

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS, I have a LaunchScreen.xib file displayed on startup.  If the user touches the screen while the splash screen is displayed, I would like to advance immediately to the first ViewController.  How do I recognize the touch?

Comment: Add a UItapGestureRecognizer to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, the Launch Screen time cannot be shortened, which is what a "tap" would do. This is the time it takes for the app to initialize on the device, and it varies based on the processing power of the device.

I would suggest creating a VC that looks identical to your launch screen, and then have it load right after the launch-screen. Then, you can have the user tap on that VC to advance to your current first VC.